# how to make an image repeat in html

Tags: html, css

I have the following image as png file. http://pctechtips.org/pics/dot-line.png and I would like to create a horizontal line for my tic tac toe header section. Instead of haveing an image for the whole header, I think it would be better break the images into smaller elements; therefore, it will be easy to resize and adapt to different screen sizes. Anyway how can I make it repeat X. pen: https://codepen.io/zentech/pen/xLRzGr
html

```
<div class="container">
  <!-- header -->
  <div class="header">
    <img src="http://pctechtips.org/pics/header-logo-tictactoe.png">
    <img src="http://pctechtips.org/pics/dot-line.png">
  </div>
  <div class="tictactoe">      
    <!-- first row (3 square) -->
    <div class="row">
      <div id="0" class="square right bottom"></div><!-- 
      --><div id="1" class="square right bottom"></div><!--
      --><div id="2" class="square bottom"></div>      
    </div>

    <!-- second row (3 square) -->
    <div class="row">
      <div id="3" class="square right bottom"></div><!--
      --><div id="4" class="square right bottom"></div><!--
      --><div id="5" class="square bottom"></div>      
    </div> 

    <!-- third row (3 square) -->
    <div class="row">
      <div id="6" class="square right"></div><!--
      --><div id="7" class="square right"></div><!--
      --><div id="8" class="square"></div>      
    </div>     
  </div> 
  <div class="controls">
    <h2 id="message">Message:</h2>
    <button type="button" class="resetGame">Reset Game</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat ?

Answer (score 0):

In your header, remove the "dots" image and replace it with an hr (or another element of your choosing).

```
<div class="header">
    <img src="http://pctechtips.org/pics/header-logo-tictactoe.png">
    <hr />
  </div>
```

Then in your CSS, you can style the hr (given a height of 50px to match the height of the dots image) like this:

```
hr {
  height: 50px;
  background: url('http://pctechtips.org/pics/dot-line.png') 50% 50% repeat-x;
  border: none;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/Vzrjjj

Comment: @miatech Apologies if I misunderstood your question, what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: "I have the following image as png file. http://pctechtips.org/pics/dot-line.png and I would like to create a horizontal line... Anyway how can I make it repeat X" - To me, it sounds like you wanted to create an image that repeats on the x-axis. If this isn't the case, how can I improve my answer to help you?

Comment: @miatech In that case, I don't understand why my answer didn't satisfy your question. It uses a repeating image on the x-axis. Am I missing something?